# Why does importing from a .dae or .fbx format result in loss of animation?

Tags: import, collada

I've got a scene of about 30 nulls moving around in either LightWave or Softimage.  I export either a dae or fbx file from one of those apps, import into Blender.  The nulls are in the correct position from the first frame of the animation, and data has been imported, but it hasn't been applied to the xyz coordinates for each null.  The data is listed as, "no path".  However, if I originate the same animation in Blender, then save it as either a dae or fbx, then re-import into Blender, it works no problem.  How can I fix this?  Thanks, Hal Dace

I have now tested with actual geometry, same result.

I have now determined that importing fbx does not misdirect data, as does dae, but loses it completely.  Except that the static position of the nulls is correct from the first frame of the original animation.

Comment: So to clarify, the animation of the nulls is not being imported, correct?

Comment: Yes.  Each channel in the F-Curve Editor says no path, instead of xyz, which is what the channels should be.  So the data's there, but it's not being utilized.